# Nested else and if methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, nested

I just got started in Python programming. This week, we've been learning basic commands such as for, while, if and else. The point is that I got stuck at a point of the following exercise:

I am to design a programme which has to ascertain whether the day entered by the user is Monday - Friday or at the weekend. If the entered value is either Saturday or Sunday, then it has to display 'Congratulations, you're in the low-cost section'. If the value entered is other than that and is any value Monday-Friday, only then the user has to be asked for the hour. Depending on the hour value entered, it has to display different messages (only 3 options available).

My attempt at this has been the following:

[image: Code]
[image: Process][image: Output]

As you'll see if you type in 'Saturday' it asks you for the hour when it shouldn't! Do you have any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code and printouts inline as text (not as screenshots).

Comment: You need to check the guidelines on post a good question on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of the OR-Operator semantics:

`if a == 0 or 1` does not check if a equals either 0 or 1. It checks if a is zero OR if  another condition is fullfilled. 1 is always true, therefore the whole expression is always true.

In your case that principle applies. You specify the if-conditions like that:

`if hourEvaluate == day[0] or day[1] ...` which does not compare hourEvaluate to `day[1]`.

You need to change to `if hourEvaluate == day[0] or hourEvaluate == day[1] or hourEvaluate == day[2] ...`